# Why is ReadFile giving wrong values when I expect 126 and it gives 254?

Tags: c++, serial-port, readfile

I am using C++ ReadFile method to receive test data from a serial port microcontroller.

The ReadFile reads values: 254 254 254 254
While the documentation states that they should be:  126 126 126 126

Brief C++ Source :

```
unsigned char BUFFER[24];    
bool result = ::ReadFile(serial.GetCommHandle(), BUFFER, sizeof(BUFFER), &dwBytesRead, &ov);
```

I have tried setting the type of BUFFER as byte without any success:

```
byte BUFFER[24];
```

And in case a byte has been received, I attempt to read everything using printf()

```
printf("%x ", (unsigned char)BUFFER[i]);
```

using direct cast in the above statement to cast buffer as unsigned int or signed int does not produce the desired output.

In case you need, Here are my DCB Settings:

```
dcb.BaudRate = DWORD(BAUD_115200);
dcb.ByteSize = BYTE(8);
dcb.Parity   = BYTE(NOPARITY);
dcb.StopBits = BYTE(ONESTOPBIT);    
dcb.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_HANDSHAKE;
dcb.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_HANDSHAKE;
dcb.XonLim = 0;
dcb.XoffLim = 0;
dcb.EofChar = 0;
dcb.ErrorChar = 0;
dcb.EvtChar = 0;
dcb.XonChar = 0;
dcb.XoffChar = 0;
```

Please note that I have tried all different printf formattings with no success. various formatting structures found at: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=vs-2019

So far I have been reading the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/synchronization-and-overlapped-input-and-output , however I have not been able to address my programming problem.

Edit/Update : 
I set these parameters in a new c# project and used the .NET 4.6's SerialPort class and it started working using the following parameters:

```
        _serialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
        _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
        _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 4;
        _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 40;
        _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        _serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
        _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        _serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
        _serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
```

What is wrong with my c++'s flags? The reason behind my choice for c++ is that it gives me access to settings unavailable in the .net version of SerialPort such as DCB Flags.

Comment: Where is the data that you're trying to read come from?  You mention `WriteFile` in your question but don't show the code that calls it.

Comment: You are correct. WriteFile was unnecessary for this question (I updated the question). I was just trying to provide some context of which I am working on.
The data I read comes from a microcontroller. The documentation of the Microcontroller states that you should receive 126 126 126 126 as unsigned chars, While I am reading 254s which is odd.

Comment: I tested using Eltima serial monitor, there is a depreciated c++ sample application (without any source code) attached to the documentation which receives 126s as well. 
So you are suspecting the DCB settings?

Comment: Is `byte` a signed type on your platform? If so, you are casting a value that is incorrect.

Comment: To test your input, I replace the byte with "unsigned char" and "unsigned int" without any success.

Comment: The documentation has not provided me with the source code. It has been documented 10 years ago and I have no access to the authors of the documentation.

Comment: I updated the results in my question, my c# test application produced the desired results, the question is, why my c++ version fails to produce the same?